# Where is the Qt Maintenance Tool?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

I've installed QtCreator in Kubuntu 15.10 through apt-get and it say my computer doesn't have the required Qt Kit and can be installed through Qt Maintenance Tool.

But I don't think I have Qt Maintenance Tool in my start menu and didn't found it in Synaptic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install Qt development packages `qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev` through `apt-get`.

Comment: The versions of these packages provided with Ubuntu 19.10 do not contain the Qt Maintenance Tool. Can't find it in any of the Qt5 Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 2):

I found the maintenance tool binary for my installation at `/opt/Qt5.7.0/MaintenanceTool` on Ubuntu 14.04.

I found it by using the [`locate` tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)):

```
sudo apt-get install mlocate
sudo updatedb
locate -i maintenance | grep -i qt
```

Anyways, using the maintenance tool with the `apt` provided package was a rabbit hole with other problems.  I ended up installing a fresh version of QtCreator from the universal linux binary install provided at [qt.io](https://www.qt.io/) installing into `$HOME/Qt`.  Uses of *that* maintenance tool actually do work and I can upgrade Qt Versions easily.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a Kit of your own choice in:

> **Tools** > **Options** > **Build & Run** > **Kits** > (press) **Add** (button on the right side) > (give the **Unnamed** kit a name, or not, your choice) > **Apply** | **OK**

*Note: The default kit, which comes pre-installed didn't work for me. So I recreated one.*

You can select compiler kits, tools, platform, version of qt and anything else for your kit if you need to.

Comment: To clarify, for Qt Creator installed via `apt-get` as by the OP, this answer only works for the Kit for desktop Qt development. Because that's the Qt version installed by `apt`. To develop for Android and the like, you need a Qt version compiled for Android. And that is only available within the Qt Maintenance Tool or when using the installer from the Qt website.

Comment: @tanius yes, this was not meant as an answer for Android.