# Where are Qt Charts and Qt Data Visualization located in Ubuntu repository

Tags: 17.04, qt, qt5, visualization

I'm trying to install *[Qt Charts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html)* and *[Qt Data Visualization](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-index.html)* modules from Ubuntu repository, but I cannot find them. Are they available in the repository?

Ubuntu: Zesty (17.04)

I get the following error while I'm trying to compile [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-linechart-example.html) from Qt website.

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt can sometimes be difficult.

Here is what I do when trying to identify packages in Ubuntu :

1. Search the repos - https://packages.ubuntu.com/

not in the repos

2. Search for a ppa - https://www.google.com/search?q=ppa+qt+charts

Yields - https://gist.github.com/martyngigg/1e20eff3f6397dd118220317a3adf358

Instructions on that page, not sure if it will or will not work for you.

Qt data may be more difficult and may not be open source.

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qtdatavisualization-getting-started.html

On ubuntu see [Where is the Qt Maintenance Tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699878/where-is-the-qt-maintenance-tool)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me, because I want to find them in Ubuntu repository not ouside of official repositories. Also, Qt Charts and Qt Data Visualizations have been released under GPL from Qt 5.7 onwards. https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/16/qt-5-7-released/

Comment: They are not in the Ubuntu repos. Ubuntu tends to lag a bit in packages, especially with Qt, new qt is generally not added pending a new release.